# Why does my autofs service do not run on my linux container?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

When deploying my system using kubernetes, autofs service is not running on the container.

running `service autofs status` returns the following error:

[FAIL] automount is not running ... failed!

running `service autofs start` returns the following error:

[....] Starting automount.../usr/sbin/automount: test mount forbidden or incorrect kernel protocol version, kernel protocol version 5.00 or above required.
failed (no valid automount entries defined.).

- /etc/fstab file does exist in my file system.

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't load the module for it. Official documenatation: [autofs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs).

One of the reason for this error too,can be **/tmp** directory is not present or it's permission/ownership is wrong.
Check if your **/etc/fstab** file exists.

Useful blog: [nfs-autofs](https://www.linuxtechi.com/automount-nfs-share-in-linux-using-autofs/).